# How can I directly browse or transfer pictures from iOS without using the Nikon Wireless Mobile Utility app?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer, wireless, wifi

I have a Nikon D5300 with built in WiFi. I'm interested in tinkering/hacking with its network protocol and transferring photos wirelessly, without using the Nikon Wireless Mobile Utility application for iOS/Android. I find the app buggy and unaesthetically pleasing, slow to use, and while it technically works with iPad, it isn't made for it.

After looking into the network protocols and ports, I found this:

http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D4NWG_En_01.pdf

It talks about how you can use FTP on some WiFi chips in different camera models, but I'm not sure if it includes mine.

I know there are two ports used for the connection; one is 15740 to transfer the photos, and one is 5353 to connect. I also found that the chip uses the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP).

Is there a way I can directly browse or transfer pictures from iOS without using the Nikon Wireless Mobile Utility app? There are multiple FTP programs for iOS, can one of these or similar programs be used to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somethink like '$ gphoto2 --port=ptpip:192.168.0.1 ...'?

http://gphoto.org (libgphoto2 has a ptpip.c file)

http://photolifetoys.blogspot.be/2012/08/control-your-camera-with-gphoto2-via.html

Answer (score 0):

I also own a 5300, and there is a Windows application that does what you are looking for, though you may struggle with one for iOS. I have been toying with the idea of writing something in Python that is more robust, but haven't gone further than thinking just yet, though the pdf that you found is very interesting.

Regards 
Stevo

Comment: What's the app for windows?