# Automatically send raw photos to PC

Tags: wifi, wifi-sd

I want to set up my Canon T5i to transmit photos wirelessly to a nearby PC/Mac in semi-real-time (as I take them). I can stay fairly close to the PC, but need to be mobile enough that I can roam about 30 feet with the camera. Ideally, it would transmit the photos in RAW format.

It seems like a Wi-fi enabled SD card would be the way to go for this. The Eye-Fi series of cards looked about right; however, it seems like maybe they've been discontinued and their website says something about licensing their technology to Toshiba.

I'm wondering what serious photographers are using to handle this type of scenario these days? Is there a better/newer product that leapfrogs the Eye-Fi cards? If not, should I be looking to eBay to buy a used Eye-Fi? Are those even mildly supported any longer?

Comment: If the technology has been licensed to Toshiba, then get a Toshiba equivalent, as the technology will be the same, surely? There seem to be plenty available on the Amazon UK store

Comment: You can check this Q/A (even it is for Nikon but the software support Canon also):  https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87579/is-there-a-way-that-would-allow-me-to-automatically-instantly-send-photos-to-p/87587#87587

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what serious photographers are using to handle this type of scenario these days?

Canon's 1-Series, 5-Series, 6-series, and 7-series have optional hardware or built-in Wi-Fi to do this. The [Wireless File Transmitters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B6OU936) for models in this series are rather pricey. They've been available for the 1-Series and 5-Series cameras since 2004 and for the 7-series cameras since its introduction in 2009.

Some of the newest models, such as the 6D, 6D Mark II, and 5D Mark IV, have Wi-Fi and even Bluetooth or NFC built in.

The 7D Mark II, the 5Ds and 5Ds R don't have built-in Wi-Fi, but are compatible with the very affordable [W-E1 Wi-Fi Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KURGUZG) that fits in the SD card slot on these three camera models, each of which also includes a CF card slot as well.

Beginning with the 70D, the x0D Series has had built-in Wi-Fi. Prior to the 70D, the x0D Series had [Wireless File Transmitters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VUKQQ2) available beginning in 2004 with the 20D. Though the more recent WFT units for the x0D series are not as pricey as the WFTs for the xD Series, they were still expensive compared to an Eye-Fi card.

These are the types of cameras 'serious' photographers tend to use if they need to transfer files wirelessly as they take them.

Canon's lower end cameras, such as the Rebel line, did not offer such functionality until the Rebel T6i/750D was introduced with built-in Wi-Fi, NFC, and low power Bluetooth in 2015.

> If not, should I be looking to eBay to buy a used Eye-Fi? Are those even mildly supported any longer?

Your Rebel T5i/700D is compatible with and supports Eye-Fi cards.

From the comments:

> Point taken, though Wi-fi enabled cameras are still relatively new. Many pro photographers probably don't have them yet. I wonder what those who want Wi-fi connectivity are doing?

The 1-series and 5-Series has had compatible Wireless File Transmitters available since the WFT-1 was introduced in **2004**.

The 6-Series has had built-in Wi-Fi since its **introduction** in 2012.

The 7-series has had WFT units available since **introduced** in 2009.

The 20D through 50D have had WFT units available since **2004**.
The 60D (2010) had no available WFT unit but was the first x0D model compatible with Eye-Fi.
The 70D (2012) and 80D (2016) have built-in Wi-Fi.

Additionally, many pro and enthusiast Canon models have dual card slots with at least one SD/SDHC/SDXC slot:
The 1-Series from 2004 until 2012 (the 1D X (2012) has dual CF slots and the 1D X Mark II (2016) has 1 CFast slot and one CF slot)
The 5-Series since 2012 (the 5D Mark III is compatible with and has many features available via Eye-Fi)
The 7-Series since 2014

Comment: Point taken, though Wi-fi enabled cameras are still relatively new. Many pro photographers probably don't have them yet. I wonder what those who want Wi-fi connectivity are doing?

Comment: Also, was thinking more about whether or not an Eye-Fi purchase is a good investment, given it seems like maybe they're more or less discontinued. Thinking maybe something else is more widely used these days? But maybe not...

Comment: @MattHamann The various WFT units for the 1 series bodies have been available beginning in 2004. The first WFT for the 5-Series and the x0D was also the WFT-1 in 2004. The 7-Series has had WFT units available since its introduction in 2009. The 6-Series has had built-in WiFi since their introduction in 2012.

Comment: @MattHamann What is more widely used in the Canon universe are what are described in the answer: WFT units that have been available for all but the Rebel series since 2004, or built-in Wi-Fi units on some of the more recent camera bodies since 2012.

Comment: There are also plenty of pro photogs using Eye-Fi cards in the second memory card slot of their pro cameras with dual card slots: The 1-series since 2004, the 5-series since 2012, and the 7-series since 2014 have dual card slots with at least one of them SD/SDHC/SDXC. The 6-series only has a single memory card slot but it has always had built-in Wi-Fi. The x0D series only have a single slot but didn't have Wi-Fi built in until the 70D introduced in 2013. The last xoD to have a WFT unit available was the 50D (2008). The 60D (2010) is compatible with Eye-Fi.

Comment: "Also, was thinking more about whether or not an Eye-Fi purchase is a good investment..." Any Wi-Fi hardware is not an investment (something one expects to sell for more than one paid for it), it is an expense (something one expects to use productively as its value steadily depreciates).